Ipod 4 disabled for 24 milion of minutes? How can i retrieve data?
I am addressing the more "geeky" of the group. I have an old 4th generation iPod Touch that, after years, I decided to turn on again, to see photos and videos I had taken now more than 10 years ago. The problem is that when I turn it on I am presented with the lock screen which says that the Ipod is disabled for a good 24 million minutes (doing a quick calculation that's over 40 years). Checking on the internet I saw that this is a problem that other people have had as well. The solutions I found are not many. The main one is to restore the device by connecting it to the computer and via iTunes. The problem with this method is that it obviously resets the device so unless you have an old backup you will lose all your data. Other methods are to use third-party programs. I have tried different programs, to recover the data, or just unlock the device, but all these programs ask me to unlock the device by entering the pin to authorize access, but I cannot because precisely the iPod is disabled. Do you have any suggestions? My intent is just to recover the data. Thank you to those who will respond.

Welcome to Ask Different.  You don’t have to restore it when you connect to a computer. Just perform a sync. If you can’t follow the linked answers, please edit this to narrow down why the existing answers don’t work for you and we can see about reopening this.  Also, see the [tour] as we appreciate minimum chit chat like thanks in advance, and you all are awesome people compliments that distract from a clean presentation of the facts, your research and what you need to do.

Thank you for the answer. I saw the answers to the other questions. The problem is that I can't sync because the device is not associated with any computer, so if I connect it to my computer with iTunes, the device is detected but you can't access it because you have to enter the passcode into the device to do that, which I can't do because the device is disabled. The only thing I can do from iTunes is restore the device. I also don't have any backup, so even if I wanted to, I couldn't restore the device until I recovered the data

The questions I linked have been viewed 75 thousand times so you are likely out of luck since any easy method would surely have surfaced by now to crack this security feature on an iPod touch.
